# Two or more "Radio" button group iy doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have this code

```
function dataSelect23124() {
  $( "#result1" ).html( $('input:checked').val() + " is checked!" );
};

function dataSelect23123() {
  $( "#result" ).html( $('input:checked').val() + " is checked!" );
};
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9ondfp8/1/)

But im getting a problem to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div class="rrr">
<input type="radio" name="selector_" value="post_active" id="posts">Post
<br>
<input type="radio" name="selector_" value="page_active" id="pages">Page
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="rrr">
<input type="radio" name="selector_1" value="post_active1" id="posts1">Post
<br>
<input type="radio" name="selector_1" value="page_active1" id="pages1">Page
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("input:radio[name=selector_]").click(function () {
    var value = $('input:radio[name=selector_]:checked').val();
    $("#result").html(value + " is checked");
});

$("input:radio[name=selector_1]").click(function () {
    var value = $('input:radio[name=selector_1]:checked').val();
    $("#result1").html(value + " is checked");
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's great - it worked!!! Thank you Tanya! But if i create dynamicaly radio butonn groups. For example - name="selector_",name="selector_1",name="selector_2" and etc. How apply this JS script? I think must create one fuction for all groups. But how it create i don't know. Please help.